# MYSQL Ignores AND clause in my query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, the AND state = 1 is being ignored, i get all the states instead of only what is equal to 1. Where is my mistake here?

```
$query = "
                SELECT state, id, variable, name, {$columns->specific}, {$columns->allExcept}, {$columns->specificExclude}, {$columns->relationAllExcept}, repeatable

                FROM #__epc_fieldsgroups
                WHERE FIND_IN_SET({$relationRecordId}, {$columns->specific})

                OR {$columns->allExcept} != 0
                AND FIND_IN_SET({$relationRecordId}, {$columns->allExcept}) = 0

                AND state = 1
                ORDER BY ordering
             ";
```

Comment: All I guess you need parentheses.

Comment: What duplicated about that? its a completely different query with a completely different syntax. The solution posted there is not valid for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define start and end of AND using parentheses

```
$query = "
                SELECT state, id, variable, name, {$columns->specific}, {$columns->allExcept}, {$columns->specificExclude}, {$columns->relationAllExcept}, repeatable

                FROM #__epc_fieldsgroups
                WHERE FIND_IN_SET({$relationRecordId}, {$columns->specific})

                OR {$columns->allExcept} != 0
                AND {FIND_IN_SET({$relationRecordId}, {$columns->allExcept}) = 0}

                AND {state = 1}
                ORDER BY ordering
             ";
```

Comment: Doing so ending up with a syntax error. Am i missing something?